# DLL files pulling old code

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a web site I recently migrated from .net 1.0 to 3.5.  Entered the new code into source safe under a different name.  Now, I cannot edit the code behind files for aspx pages.  Any physical interface changes are fine, but the underlying code behind changes will be completely ignored.  I've checked dll files, they are loading from the proper place.  But it appears that they are still referencing old code files.  I have no idea how or where to find this stuff and googling hasn't brought any results. Any help is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Vault, a decendant of SourceSafe places references to the main repository in the VS-project file. My guess is that sourcesafe does the same. Can't verify it for you as I haven't been near the MS SS (pun intended) since ages...

I suggest you open the .csproj (of .vbproj) with a plain text editor and remove the bindings to SourceSafe from there.

Look however at the bright side of this small set back:
An excelent moment and reason to drop sourcesafe and start using a modern VCS :-)

BTW a shortcut to be able to edit the files is to reset the readonly attribute on the files. MS-SS uses that advanced technique to protect the files.